# WPF Selected ListBoxItem with custom border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, itemtemplate

I'm trying to create a ListBoxItem template, that will be with rounded border at selection.
I got this xaml, which doesn't work on selection:

```
<ListBox x:Name="filtersListBox" Grid.Row="1" 
         Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding FilterItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Orange" 
                        Margin="2" Background="Transparent" Name="itemBorder"
                        Width="275" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Focusable="True">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1" ShadowDepth="2" Color="DarkOrange" Opacity="0.3"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsFocused" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                                                To="2"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                                                To="0"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="10, 2"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So this is the ListBox that I'm working on. 
The MouseEnter and MouseLeave events, work great! 
However, the trigger of UIElement.IsFocused is not working.

Any advice would be very appreciated! :)
Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so easy to do, I'm quite surprised that nobody suggested this yet. Either define two `DataTemplate`s or two `ControlTemplate`s, one for the default look and one for the selected look. Then just add this `Style` (this first example uses `DataTemplate`s):

```
<Style x:Key="SelectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You would use it like this:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SelectionStyle}" ... />
```

Here is the other example using two `ControlTemplate`s (used in the same way):

```
<Style x:Key="SelectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I'll leave you to define what you want the items to look like as you know that best. One last note... if you use this method (using `ControlTemplate`s), make sure that you add a `ContentPresenter` so that the content of the items will still be shown. See the [Control.Template Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting Focusable property to true. By default the propery is false.

Take a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If that doesnt help then maybe this approach will fit you more.

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="ListBoxItem_GotFocus"/>
        <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="ListBoxItem_LostFocus"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set the Template for ItemContainerStyle, then you can use the Trigger with property IsSelected = true. See code below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <collections:ArrayList  x:Key="StringArray">
        <system:String>Hei</system:String>
        <system:String>Hei</system:String>
        <system:String>Hei</system:String>
        <system:String>Hei</system:String>
    </collections:ArrayList>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="filtersListBox" Grid.Row="1" 
     Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
     ItemsSource="{StaticResource StringArray}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Orange" 
                    Margin="2" Background="Transparent" Name="itemBorder"
                    Width="275" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Focusable="True">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1" ShadowDepth="2" Color="DarkOrange" Opacity="0.3"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="itemBorder" Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Orange" 
                    Margin="2" Background="Transparent" Name="itemBorder"
                    Width="275" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Focusable="True">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1" ShadowDepth="2" Color="DarkOrange" Opacity="0.3"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsFocused" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                                            To="2"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                                            To="0"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" Margin="10, 2"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```